# Java Mask Formatting for Range of Dates

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, mask, simpledateformat

I am working on a project that pulls files from a third party FTP site where the files are defined by a mask, lets say **'XXX'MMddy.FILE** where **XXX** is the vendor code and **y** is the last digit of the year.

My application is only concerned with the files matching the mask, but does not care about the actual date on the file. Currently, we are building a list of dates a month back with the Java `Calendar` object and iterating through it to create each possible mask until one matches or is determined invalid. I feel like there should be a better way to do this...

So to reiterate, in a consise question, is there a way to use the mask without creating an instance of each date to compare to the actual filename?

i.e. XXX04022.FILE conforms to XXXMMddy.FILE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement a FilenameFilter to use on [`File.listFiles`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29):

```
public class YourFilenameFilter extends java.io.FilenameFilter
{
    public boolean accept(java.io.File file, String name)
    {
        boolean shouldAccept = false;
        if(name!=null)
        {
            java.util.regex.Pattern p = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].FILE");
            java.util.regex.Matcher m = p.matcher(name);
            if(m.matches()) {
                shouldAccept = true;
            }
        }
        return shouldAccept;
    }
}
```

Comment: why not just an `acceptFromFTP(String localname): boolean` method with a single `return localname.matches("\\w{3}\\d{6}[.]FILE")` ? Of course, it would be pretty wise to feed this the input of some kind of FTP `ls` query instead of `mget *` and match afterwards.

Comment: This is great, exactly what I was looking for. Only other question I have is the .FILE extension can change, but there are only specific ones that I care about, i.e. (.ABC, .CDE, .FAS, .CAD). How would I support that?

Comment: Use the pattern: `"^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{6}[.](FILE|ADC|CDE|FAS|CAD)$"`.